# Can the same input appear in a block multiple times?

Tags: available-outputs, output-selection, blockchain-data

I have questions regarding two situations:

1. Suppose there are two transactions being made. One uses inputs A, B, and C, with C being the real one. Another is sent using inputs A, D, and E, with E being the real one. Is it possible for both of these transactions to be recorded in the same block? A would appear twice, even though it was never actually spent.
2. Suppose there are two transactions being made. One uses inputs A, B, and C, with A being the real one. Another is send using inputs A, D, and E, with E being the real one. Is it possible for both of these transactions to be recorded in the same block? A would appear twice, even though it was only spent once.

If it is not possible for the same input to be included in a block multiple times, how does the network choose which transactions get priority?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both cases are possible. Filler.